# Escaping braces doesn't seem to work in SendKeys

Tags: powershell, sendkeys

I do not get {} when sending keys to VSCode:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Untitled-1')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('`{`}')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('Hello World 2~')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not PowerShell you have to escape your braces from in this case. It's SendKeys.

To use literal braces in SendKeys you have surround them in braces like other special characters.

```
$wshell.SendKeys('{{}{}}')
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of these characters, enclose it within braces ({}). For example, to specify the plus sign, use "{+}". **To specify brace characters, use "{{}" and "{}}"**. Brackets ([ ]) have no special meaning to SendKeys, but you must enclose them in braces. In other applications, brackets do have a special meaning that might be significant when dynamic data exchange (DDE) occurs.

emphasis mine.

Comment: I tried $wshell.SendKeys('{{}}') but gets this error : Value does not fall within the expected range. At line:1 char:1 + $wshell.SendKeys('{{}}')

Comment: @user310291 I didn't read what I linked to properly. Does this work `$wshell.SendKeys("{{}{}}")` as that should be what the docs suggested